# Any known bounds for convex function say $f$ with $L$-Lipschitz continuous gradient: $( x - y)^T A \left( \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

There are several known bounds for a convex function say $f$ with $L$-Lipschitz continuous gradient, for instance,

\begin{align}
\left( x - y \right)^T  \left( \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\right) \leq L \| x - y \|_2^2, \forall x, y .
\end{align}
Exhaustive list can example be found [here](http://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/Lipschitz-gradient).

Now, I am wondering if there is any known bound for this case, 
\begin{align}
\left( x - y \right)^T {\color{red} A} \left( \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\right) \leq \ {\color{red}?}, \forall x, y ,
\end{align}
where $A$ is a square matrix .

**Questions**

1. If there is any lower bound, what is it and how to derive that?
2. Moreover, what are the requirements on such a matrix $A$? Positive (semi)definite? (except the trivial case where matrix $A$ is a scaled identity)

Comment: If $A$ is positive definite, then it induces an innner product defined by $\langle u, v\rangle_A := u^TAv$. You can definitely consider Lipschitzness w.r.t the norm defined by $\|u\|_A := \sqrt{\langle u, u\rangle_A}$.

Comment: @dohmatob Thank you for your comment. So, are you saying that the inequality is $(x-y)^T A (\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)) \leq L \| x - y \|_A^2$ given $A$ is positive definite?

Answer (score 1):

**Attempt**: Does the below make sense?

If we invoke Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, then 
\begin{align}
\left( x - y \right)^T {\color{red} A} \left( \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\right) &\leq \underbrace{\left\| {\color{red} A} \right\|_2}_{ = \sigma_{\rm max}\left( {\color{red} A} \right)} \left\| x - y \right\| \ \underbrace{\left\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \right\|}_{ \leq L \left\| x - y \right\|} \\
&\leq L \ \sigma_{\rm max}\left( {\color{red} A} \right) \left\| x - y \right\|^2, \quad \forall x, y ,
\end{align}
where $\sigma_{\rm max}\left( {\color{red} A} \right)$ is the maximum singular value of matrix ${\color{red} A} $.

Comment: No need to write the transpose here, no? I definitely agree with what you've written.

Comment: Indeed, thank you.