# Inequality for convex function say $f$ with $L$-Lipschitz continuous gradient: $( x - y)^T \left( \alpha \nabla f(x) - \beta \nabla f(y)\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

> Any known known bound for a convex function say $f$ with $L$-Lipschitz continuous gradient (for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, which can be $\alpha \neq \beta$):

- $( x - y)^T \left( {\color{red} \alpha} \nabla f(x) - {\color{red} \beta} \nabla f(y)\right) \leq \ \color{red} ? $
- $\left\| {\color{red} \alpha} \nabla f(x) - {\color{red} \beta} \nabla f(y)\right\| \leq \ \color{red} ? $

(Related to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3662868/any-known-bounds-for-convex-function-say-f-with-l-lipschitz-continuous-gradi), but not really.)

Comment: If $\alpha$ is near to $\beta$, you can divide by $\alpha$ and bound the thing you are after in terms of the inequality from your previous question. (Let $g$ be the gradient. After dividing you can rewrite the thing you are dotting with as : $(g(x) - g(y) ) + (g(y) - (\beta/\alpha) g(y) ) $.  The dot product with the first part you already know how to control. The dot product with the second part is bounded by how similar $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are, and a bound on the gradient.) Not sure if this inequality is useful for anything though...

Comment: @LorenzoNajt Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is the tightest bound which you can achieve.
But here is my attempt for part 1:

Let's take the case $\alpha,\beta >0$ and  $\alpha \geq \beta$

\begin{align} 
( x - y)^T \left( { \alpha} \nabla f(x) - {\beta} \nabla f(y)\right) &= \frac{(\alpha + \beta)}{2}(x - y)^T(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)) \  + \frac{(\alpha - \beta)}{2}(x-y)^T(\nabla f(x) + \nabla f(y)) \\
&\leq \frac{(\alpha+\beta)}{2}L||x-y||^2 + \frac{(\alpha - \beta)}{2}(x-y)^T(\nabla f(x) + \nabla f(y))
\end{align}
The second term can grow unbounded in general case unless $f$ is Lipschitz continous.
Assuming $f$ is $G$-Lipshitz continuous the bound becomes
then we have

$$
|\nabla f(x)| \leq G 
$$
Then by Cauchy-Scwarz inequality we have:
 \begin{align} 
( x - y)^T \left( { \alpha} \nabla f(x) - {\beta} \nabla f(y)\right) 
&\leq \frac{(\alpha+\beta)}{2}L||x-y||^2 + \frac{(\alpha - \beta)}{2}*(2G||x-y||)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. Looks interesting. 

For the second part, we can assume that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous. Would you like to show me the possible bound? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please verify :)

Comment: Looks good to me. Thank you.